# Not able to launch URL from ionic2 Cordova InAppBrowser Plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using InAppBrowser Plugin for launching a link from my application.But when i do click then it goes to localhost:/URL/.. 

What am i doing wrong?

```html
 <p class="title-heading">INTERNET:</p><a href="launch('{{navigateUrl}}')">{{navigateUrl}}</a>
```

```html
 launch(url)
  {
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
      cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url,"_system","location=true");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue..
i used the following code

```html
 launch()
  {
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
      // cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url,"_system","location=true");
      let browser=new InAppBrowser(this.navigateUrl,'_blank');
    });
  }
```

It will open up a new tab in chrome as well...

Answer (score 0):

This is a Cordova plugin, which requires the Cordova platform to be running in order to function.

Try `ionic run android` (or ios) to test it on a device or emulator instead.

Comment: i am running on localhost...windows environment..i changed the code and added a button instead..now it is going to localhost/url

Comment: Can you try the command I mentioned above? Cordova does not run when tested in browser, you have to run your application on a device or emulator in order to test Cordova functionality.